# How to insert a trajectory on a quiver based phase portrait

Tags: matlab, ode

I've done a phase portrait for a system of ODE's i've been working, it was quite simple so i just used 6 lines of code on matlab, using quiver to plot the field, but i wanted to add a trajectory given an initial condition, but i have no clue on what to do
[Phase portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWEWD.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stream3 function in matlab.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stream3.html

I assume from your image that you have a velocity field (U, V, W) supported by coordinates (X,Y,Z)

given an initial point (XS, YS, ZS)

you use the stream line function like so:

```
lin = stream3(X,Y,Z,U,V,W,XS,YS,ZS)
```

to plot the result

```
streamline(lin)
```